# How to find out if override done successfully or not in UVM factory?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

How to find out if a class type has been overridden successfully or not in UVM factory?
To figure out the answer I implemented "`find_override_by_name`" method as the below.

```
       virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    
      uvm_object_wrapper wrapper1;

        wrapper1 = factory.find_override_by_name("write_ahb_item", {super.get_full_name(), ".",""});
        $display("wrapper1=%m", wrapper1);

        super.end_of_elaboration_phase(phase);
    uvm_top.print_topology();
  endfunction
```

But I get a wrong return value

```
wrapper1=$unit_0x4ccdf83b.test2.end_of_elaboration_phasenull
```

How do I correctly I can get a `find_override_by_name` method to know whether it is overridden well or not ?

For your understand I implemented in https://edaplayground.com/x/7ikn

Comment: @toolic sorry for type. find_override_by_name was what I asked.

Comment: @toolic how can I tell what is running if my factory overrides don’t take? or if factory failed, but UVM produced no error message. The code ran fine. how can I check the override? I think there is good way than just checking the log result after ran, so I tried with "find_override_by_name "  to check.